# How to JSON unmarshal a struct in a list in a struct in Go?

Tags: json, go

How can I deserialize this JSON data into a proper struct within an array/slice within a struct? I would like to avoid deserializing to a `map`.

```
d := []byte(`{
    "a": 1,
    "b": [
        {"c": 3, "d": 4},
        {"c": 5, "d": 6}
    ]
    }`)
```

Comment: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Unmarshal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is quite intuitive:

```
d := []byte(`{
    "a": 1,
    "b": [
        {"c": 3, "d": 4},
        {"c": 5, "d": 6}
    ]
    }`)

var j struct {
    A uint
    B []struct {
        C uint
        D uint
    }
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &j); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", j)
```

The result, printed to `stdout`: `{A:1 B:[{C:3 D:4} {C:5 D:6}]}`

Comment: This works only if the type of each element is known in advance. If not, you'll need to apply more complicated tricks to map deserialization code to the right class.